# How can I get span indices for a list of strings in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have a list of strings, like this:

```hs
[Left "hey here are some words",Right "blue",Left "and some other words"]
```

And I want to get span indices of each, as is they were all part of one long string. So it would output:

```
[Left (0, 23), Right (24, 28), Left (29, 49)]
```

I can map a function over eithers using `mapEither f = fmap $ either (Left . f) (Right . f . fst)`. And so I can get a list of lengths using `lengths = mapEither length xs`.

Futhermore, I've discovered that the function I probably need to use is `scanl1`, which works like this:

```
> scanl1 (+) [23, 4, 20]
[23, 27, 47]
```

But I'm struggling to put it all together. Here's everything I have so far:

```hs
import Data.Either

testString = [Left "hey here are some words",Right "blue",Left "and some other words"]

getIndices :: [Either T.Text (T.Text, T.Text)] -> [Integer]
getIndices xs = mapEither length xs where
  mapEither f = fmap $ either (Left . f) (Right . f)
  lengths = mapEither length xs
  spans = scanl1 (mapEither (+)) lengths -- This is wrong
```

I'm sure I'm making this way harder for myself than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), since `Either` usually means "one value or the other", and those values usually have different meanings and don't "come together" like in your question.

Since the `Functor` and `Applicative` instances of `Either` don't allow you to work on both sides at once, you could build your own fmap function:

```
fmapEither :: (a -> b) -> Either a a -> Either b b
fmapEither f (Left a) = Left $ f a
fmapEither f (Right a) = Right $ f a
```

Then the rest is a bit easier:

```
eitherSpans list = zip <*> tail $ scanl (\acc x -> acc + either length length x) 0 list
--[(0,23),(23,27),(27,47)]

getIndices list = zipWith (\a b -> fmapEither (const a) b) (eitherSpans list) list
--[Left (0,23),Right (23,27),Left (27,47)]
--Or pointfree:
getIndices' = zipWith (fmapEither . const) =<< eitherSpans
```

EDIT

Instead of a custom `fmapEither`, you can use `bimap` from Data.Bifunctor, but it's a bit more cumbersome, since you have to repeat the mapping function:

```
fmapEither f either ≡ bimap f f either
```

Comment: The starting indices in the pairs should be 1 greater than the previous end index, according to the example. `Relude` would also provide the convenient `bimapBoth`.

Comment: @moonGoose It's unclear what's wanted, since it was apparently hand-written and and is not completely right (second index should end at 27 by that logic, for example).

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that Haskell doesn't force you to use higher-level functions for everything.  The following simple recursive definition works fine, and is easy to follow:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import qualified Data.Text as T
import Data.Either

type Side a = Either a a

testString :: [Side T.Text]
testString = [Left "hey here are some words",Right "blue",Left "and some other words"]

getIndices :: [Side T.Text] -> [Side (Int, Int)]
getIndices = go 0
  where go n (x:xs) = case x of Left  s -> make Left  s
                                Right s -> make Right s
          where make side str = side (n, n') : go (n' + 1) xs
                  where n' = n + T.length str
        go _ [] = []
```

If that's unsatisfactory, it's helpful to remember that `scanl` is a sort of special case of `mapAccumL`.  The latter allows the accumulator (the current position) to be a different type than the elements of the output list (a `Left (0,23)` or whatever).  The above `getIndices` can be converted to use `mapAccumL` like so:

```
getIndices' :: [Side T.Text] -> [Side (Int, Int)]
getIndices' = snd . mapAccumL step 0
  where step n x = case x of Left  s -> next Left  s
                             Right s -> next Right s
          where next side str = (n' + 1, side (n, n'))
                  where n' = n + T.length str
```